# Python currency calculation with API JSON

Tags: python, json, api

I'm new in this Python world, I'm trying to use an API to make basic currency calculations. I can get the output like:

`{'USD': 1.13}`

this but I want it just to be

`1.13`

The code:

```
import requests

inputCurrency = 'EUR'
outputCurrency = 'USD'

p = {"inpc":inputCurrency, "outc":outputCurrency}

url = 'https://somewebsite/api/data'

r = requests.get(url, params=p)

print(r.json())
```

Comment: Well, we won't be able to *guess* what's going wrong. You gave us the current and expected outputs, which is very useful, but we also need the *relevant* parts of the code. Please edit your question!

Comment: Added the whole code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server returned a JSON object. The `.json()` method of your `r` response decodes it, and returns the decoded object, which is a Python `dict`.

You want the value corresponding to the `'USD'` key.
Just do:

```
import requests

inputCurrency = 'EUR'
outputCurrency = 'USD'

p = {"inpc":inputCurrency, "outc":outputCurrency}

url = 'https://somewebsite/api/data'

response = requests.get(url, params=p)
json_data =response.json()
print(json_data['USD'])
```

If the structure of the data is more complicated, as in your comment:

```
json_data = { "status": 1, "data": [ { "time": "2015-08-30T07:56:28.000Z", "usd": 1.17 }, { "time": "2015-08-30T08:56:28.000Z", "usd": 1.27 }, { "time": "2015-08-30T09:56:28.000Z", "usd": 1.28 }]}
```

you could extract the relevant part:

```
data = json_data['data']
```

which is a list of dictionaries. You can then print the first one:

```
print(data[0]['usd'])
# 1.27
```

or print them all:

```
for day_value in data:
    print(day_value['usd'])
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked but what about displaying multiple outputs with the same name like:
`{
    "status": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "time": "2015-08-30T07:56:28.000Z",
            "usd": 1.17
        },
        {
            "time": "2015-08-30T08:56:28.000Z",
            "usd": 1.27
        },
        {
            "time": "2015-08-30T09:56:28.000Z",
            "usd": 1.28
        }
....`

Comment: Edited the answer.